# Set spell spelllang=en_us doesn't work for Python scripts

Tags: vim, spell-checking

In my .vimrc file, I added the following line to check the spelling.

```
set spell spelllang=en_us
```

For normal text files, it works fine, and it highlights words with wrong spellings. But in python scripts, it doesn't work. Could anyone suggest possible reason?

Comment: Do you really want vim to highlight misspelled words, which would include almost all python builtins?

Comment: maybe try it here ;) http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work"? It highlights correctly spelled words as incorrect? It doesn't highlight words at all? Give us something to go on.

Comment: @NickBailey: AFAIK Vim will only spellcheck strings, given the definitions in `syntax/python.vim`. OP: open a python file, then `:verbose set spell?` - should tell you where it was last set from.

Answer (score 1):

The `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/python.vim` syntax script enabled spell checking only for comments, strings, and docstrings; checking the Python keywords wouldn't make sense, anyway.

It may be that some configuration is messing with your spell options. Verify with

```
:setlocal spell? spelllang?
```

and re-enable if needed.